# Storing keys in binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, trie

A [resource](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/) I was reading states the following

> If we store keys in binary search tree, a well balanced BST will need time proportional to M * log N, where M is maximum string length and N is number of keys in tree.

My question is, is the above time complexity M * log N, for inserting one key in a trie, or inserting N keys into a trie, or for searching within a trie? Also, when you say Binary, how are we deciding what goes to the left and right. Is it characters from a-m on the left, and n-z in the right, in the first level of the tree, and so on?

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity  **m*logn** is when instead of using a trie, you use a balanced BST for the purpose of finding the pattern in **n** given keys.

The reason for that is as follows:
You'll construct the BST similar to as you would do it for an array of numbers. We are not considering this preprocessing step though.
Once you've constructed a balanced BST, when you search for your given pattern the worst case is that the pattern doesn't exist in the BST or exists at a leaf node. The crucial point here is that unlike a BST with numbers your comparison complexity at any node is not **O(1)** but instead **O(m)** (Since in the worst case your string at any node differs from your pattern at the last letter).
In the worst case you'll have to compare your pattern with **O(logn)** nodes.

Thus the complexity in the worst case is **O(m*logn)**.

Answer (score 0):

The article says that a trie is better than binary tree as for a string of length M, for trie it takes O(M) time and for binary tree it takes O(M logN) time.

`Trie` has multiple children not just two.

```
class trienode:
    char Character
    map<char, trienode> Children

class trie:
    trienode root
```

Below is a trie with three words `am`, `as`, `at`, and `ok`. `a` has 3 children and `o` has 1 child.

```
  (root)
   ' '
   / \
  |   |
  a   o
 /|\   \
| | |   |
m s t   k
```

Comment: @hlpPy, thanks. But my question was why is it O(M logN) time for a binary search tree. Can you please edit your answer with reasoning for this

Comment: @saltandwater, Your questions were focused on Trie. But I do not know the answer to that question.